# How can I solve this inequality?

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

How can I find the answer to this inequality for `Lambda`?

`Abs[8 \[Eta]^2 \[CapitalLambda]^2 + 8 \[Pi] \[Eta] \[Mu] + (
  16 \[Pi]^2 \[Mu]^2)/\[CapitalLambda]^2]/Abs[
 4 \[Pi] \[Eta] - (8 \[Pi]^2 \[Mu])/\[CapitalLambda]^2]<1`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: I want to have a region plot that determines the area where this condition is established. The answer of this command is somehow complicated

Answer (score 2):

```
 sol = Reduce[(Abs[8 η^2 Λ^2 + 8 π η μ + (16 π^2 μ^2)/Λ^2]/Abs[4 π η - (8 π^2 μ)/Λ^2] // 
 FullSimplify) < 1, Λ, Reals] // Simplify

 (* long expr *)

 RegionPlot3D[sol, {η, -3, 3}, {μ, -3, 3}, {Λ, -3, 3}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Although much slower, `RegionPlot3D[
  sol, {\[Eta], -3, 3}, {\[Mu], -2, 2}, {\[CapitalLambda], -3, 3}, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 75, 
  MaxRecursion -> 6] // Quiet` is far smoother.

Comment: @BobHanlon,Thanks for  smoother 3DPlot `:)`